# How to Highlight the active option in Action Sheets?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I created an action sheet containing some options

**when I select an option I want it to be highlighted.**

I took the code from here

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#action-sheets

can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can use some (S)CSS to style it with a pseudo-class like `:active` or `:hover`. To include your own CSS classes to the action sheet you could use its `cssClass` property when creating it. Like so:

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
  title: 'Ionic Action Sheet',
  cssClass: 'your-custom-class',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Button 1',
      cssClass: 'custom-button-1-class',
      handler: () => {
        console.log("Button 1 picked!");
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

By doing that, you can use custom CSS classes to style each button (option) of your action sheet, as well as the action sheet itself. If you wanted to, say, make `Button 1` have a black background whenever a user "activated" it, you could write:

```
.custom-button-1-class:active {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I tried to do it with :active when I click an option the background color change but when I reopen the action sheet the background color doesn't exist

Comment: If you want to keep the color afterwards, you'd either need to use a flag (i.e. a boolean variable in your controller) and a ng-class (or ng-style) or you can use jQuery (even Angular's jqlite should work), though I would recommend using the flag and the ng-style. If you want I can edit my answer with some example code for that.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try and tell you